# Nodejs Client IP

Tags: node.js

I'm somewhat new to NodeJS and all of its awesomeness. I'm trying to figure out how to combine [geoip-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geoip-lite) and [request-ip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip) npm packages to get the approx user location for my app.

So far I have this

```
    var requestIp = require('request-ip');
var geoip = require('geoip-lite');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//var ip = "108.219.41.178";//207.97.227.239
//var ip = req.headers['x-real-ip'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
//var ip = req.header('x-forwarded-for') || req.connection.remoteAddress;

var ip = ???

var geo = geoip.lookup(ip);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

/*app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var ipMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
    var clientIp = requestIp.getClientIp(req); 
    next();
    };
});*/

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('<html><head><head/><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html');
});


app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Hello on 3000');/*always put console.log to see if its running/working*/
    console.log(geo);
    console.log("The IP is %s", geoip.pretty(ip));
});

/*node app.js to run*/

// var ip = req.headers['x-real-ip'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

I'm having trouble figuring out to get the IP using request-ip. geoip-lite was pretty easy, took 2 mins. I guess my noobness to Nodejs isn't helping either. A code example to show me what I'm doing wrong OR not thinking of would be great.

Comment: What URL are you using to test? is it, by chance, something like `http://localhost:3000/`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is **how** you're making requests to the server.

For your tests, if you're using a url like `http://localhost:3000` then you will get `::1`

But, if try instead `http://127.0.0.1:3000` then you'll probably get the IP address: `::ffff:127.0.0.1`

Here's the Express code I used to test and I used Postman App to make requests

```
const Express = require('express');
const App = Express();

App.get('/', (req, res) => {
  var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress || req.socket.remoteAddress;
  res.send({ ip })
});

App.listen(3000);
```